# filp_open giving file pointer with no operation pointer?

Tags: linux, module, linux-kernel

I am trying to make a kernel module, it requires me to open a file in kernel space. I am using filp_open for that purpose, below is the code snipet i am trying to debug.

```
struct file *f =  NULL;
mm_segment_t oldfs;
oldfs = get_fs();
set_fs(get_ds());
f = filp_open("/home/abhijeet/project/in",O_RDONLY,0);
set_fs(oldfs);
if(!f->f_op->read)
      printk(KERN_INFO "File System does not allow reads.\n");
```

I am getting the "File System does not allow reads." Error. I am doing this inside a Virtual machine with Kernel 4.4.131

Answer (score 0):

1. why the get_fs/set_fs dance?
2. why do you think you need to open the file from the kernel
3. you are missing error checking and are setting file to NULL for no reason
4. if you check how read is implemented you will find:

__vfs_read as of 4.17rc5 (don't have 4.4 handy, but presumably it will have something of similar sort):

```
ssize_t __vfs_read(struct file *file, char __user *buf, size_t count,
                   loff_t *pos)
{
        if (file->f_op->read)
                return file->f_op->read(file, buf, count, pos);
        else if (file->f_op->read_iter)
                return new_sync_read(file, buf, count, pos);
        else
                return -EINVAL;
}
```

As you can see ->read is not the only way to read from the file. Why were you checking this pointer?

Reading files from kernel modules is typically a bad idea. Please explain what do you need this for.

Comment: It seems that 1-3 should be comment(s) to the question post, and only 4 is an answer.

Comment: I am trying to port [this](https://github.com/richygerard/file-encryption-decryption) linux kernel module to kernel 4.4.131, Till Now I am able to operate this module via driver function, but i am getting error code (-13) at line 466 in [this](https://github.com/richygerard/file-encryption-decryption/blob/master/sys_xcrypt.c) file. This function is called at line 130. The struct file * pointer passed in this check function is getting from filp_open, so i had a doubt on that, thats why this question :D

Comment: Specifically my f->f_op->read is comming null , f and f->f_op are comming other then null

Comment: this code is terrible and makes 0 sense to have it on kernel level. it only encrypts or decrypts files as passed to a special syscall. you can just have a userspace program doing the exact same thing or a library. i cannot stress enough that even if the idea made sense, this code is a non-starter. i presume this is suppose to be just an exercice in kernel programming, in which case it does not provide a good base either.